# How to increment counter for a specific list item in Flutter using Getx?

Tags: flutter, dart

Like in my sample image, below, I want to increment or decrement quantity upon button click for single list item.

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV1Jp.png)

any idea?

##solution: ##

```
addProduct(ProductModel product) {

var existing = products.indexWhere((p) => p.barcode == product.barcode);

if (existing != -1) {
  product.quantity = products[existing].quantity + 1;
  products[existing] = product; // instead of products[existing].quantity ++;
} else {
  print('adding');
  products.add(product);
}
```

}

[solution from github](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/314#issuecomment-766188728)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must copy the list you have, access the item, modify it and pass the new modified list to your GetX class.